# Personal hotspot can't be detected on Iphone 6 iOS 9.3.5

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, tethering

I want to use Internet on my laptop via Iphone 6 personal hotspot. It is very hard for my laptop(both windows and ubuntu) to detect the hotspot network. I have to disable/enable/ hotspot on my iPhone, or poweroff/poweron it for many times, refresh/enable/disable the wifi network on my laptop again and again, and suddenly, my laptop would detect the hotspot.

I have a galaxy S2, when I use it to detect the hotspot, it is easier than the laptop. I may only need to disable/enable or poweroff/poweron my iPhone for once or twice or three times and then my galaxy S2 would detect the hotspot. And strangely, if my galaxy S2 detect the hotspot, my laptop will soon detect it. It is like my galaxy S2 can be used as a detection booster, ridiculous!

What is wrong, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

for an iOS hotspot to work wirelessly you need to make sure you have the personal hotspot screen (this is the screen that displays the password to your hotspot) up whilst trying to connect and that the wifi on your iPhone is on otherwise your network will be undiscoverable.
Ubuntu should have no issue connecting to a personal hotspot over USB so that may be easier, however that might have changed since I last used Ubuntu.
Hope this helps!